# Accessing index in Django template under a for loop

Tags: html, django, backend

`#views.py`

```
.
.
.
detailedStatement = {
    'selectedOption1' : '90 degrees',
    'correctAnswer1' : '180 degrees',

    'selectedOption2' : 'angle',
    'correctAnswer2' : 'side'
}
#Above dictionary contains 200 elements



diction = {

'detailedStatement' : detailedStatement

}



return render(request, "result.html", diction);
```

So while on an html file I wanted to access the dictionary's every element via a loop. Like every element should be listed in the html table row like following.

```
| Sr | Selected Option | Correct Answer |
| 1  | 90 degrees      |  180 degrees   |
| 2  | angle           |  side          |
```

> Above table is just a representation of html table not an actual table.

But the issue I am facing is... I am not able to access its index in a dynamic way.

I wrote a for loop in Django html template but

```
{% for dr in detailedResult.items %}

<tr>
    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
    <td>{{dr.option.forloop.counter}}</td>
    <td>{{dr.answer.forloop.counter}}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

I want my code to automatically put 1 after option and answer like `option1`, `answer1`;

How can we do this?

Comment: Is this structure from your app? Do you have to use `correctAnswer1` etc? Can't you change objects to: `{"id": 1, "correctAnswer": "180 degrees"...}`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should model this with a list instead of including an index in your variable names, e.g.

```py
# views.py

detailed_statements = [{'option': '90 degrees', 'answer': '180 degrees'}, ... ] # contains 200 elements
```

Then in your template

```
{% for dr in detailed_statements %}

<tr>
    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
    <td>{{dr.option}}</td>
    <td>{{dr.answer}}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

I was a bit confused by the nested for loops in your template code - I think you only need one?